Anchored object as a nested style delimiter
Is it possible to use an anchored object as a delimiter within a nested style (InDesign 19.3 x64) or would I be better off manually setting an end to the nested style via the special characters insertion menu? The open type family (Roboto) I'm working with doesn't contain a square glyph, which would clearly be ideal here. Open to any other suggestions to achieve this end.

Yes, it's possible. Never used it myself, but just found it for you.
If you click the fourth column in Nested Styles you get a dropdown of options. One of them is called Anchored Object Marker.

Alternatively, yes you could use an End Nested Style Here character or you could use Nonbreaking Spaces in the first part which will make InDesign see them as one single "word".
You could also make a character style that changes the font of the bullets to a font with square bullets.

This is the way! Thanks a lot—I did also get a character style made up that uses an Arial square glyph as a red bullet but struggling with getting it placed in the middle of the nested style as shown in the image. Is this possible within ID?

You can paste in a bullet character in that same fourth column to target them.

Understood, thank you. This is the way to do it, for sure. Thanks so much!
